# passing parameters in url through form action in php functions

Tags: php, soap, forms, http-post

I am using web services to get the parameter from SOAP client successfully. I want to pass this parameters in url through html form so that i can connect to my system with this parameters. I have 2 functions. Function login() is to set the parameters for the connection from SOAP client and function getVehicle() to get this parameters. In getVehicle() i want to send the parameters user, hash password, dealer_number, corporate_group_id to client.php from url. And this parameters i want to send from form action without submit button.

index.php

```
    function login()
    {
        $wsdl = 'http://www.schwackenet.de/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl';
        $options = array('trace' => true);

        $params = array(
          'user' =>               utf8_encode('deshmukh'),
          'password' =>           utf8_encode('deshmukh'),
          'corporate_group_id' => '101',
          'dealer_number' =>      'INT31303',
          'dms_id' =>             'A13T2D19',
          'dms_image_url' =>      '', 
          'dms_keepalive_url' =>  '', 
          'dms_followup_url' =>   ''  
        );

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);  
        $result = $client->Login($params);      
        return $return;
    }

if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{       
    //var_dump(Login());
    $vehicle=login();
    $user_login=$vehicle['user'];
    $password=$vehicle['password'];
    $dealer_no=$vehicle['dealer_number'];
    $group_id=$vehicle['corporate_group_id'];

//form action here         

    }
```

Comment: once you have the details from the soap api, why don't you post the data to your system using CURL HTTP POST? this way, you won't need a html form / submit button?

Comment: i dont know how to use CURL HTTP and the requirement is from url only i should send this parameter and connect to my system

Comment: so your system accepts data from a GET request? i.e. `http://yoursystem.com/process.php?user=xx&password=yyy&dealer_number=123` etc..?

Comment: yes right from url i will use $_GET request to get this parameters and proceed forward to connect to my system. So from index.php file i want to send the above parameters to client.php?user=xx&password=yyy&dealer_number=123

Comment: okay, that's easy. I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the data transferred to your `client.php` as a GET request using the built-in php function `file_get_contents()` like this:

```
if ($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{       
    $vehicle=login();
    $user_login=$vehicle['user'];
    $password=$vehicle['password'];
    $dealer_no=$vehicle['dealer_number'];
    $group_id=$vehicle['corporate_group_id'];

    // send the data to your system
    $system_url = 'http://yoursite.com/path/to/client.php';
    header("Location: $system_url?user=$user_login&password=$password&dealer_number=$dealer_no&corporate_group_id=$group_id");
    exit();
}
```

If you want, you can have `client.php` reurn a "success" or "error" output and you'll have it on the `$response` variable and you can log it or do something else with it.

Comment: thank you but how can i send this information through form url to redirect to client.php. So now when i click index.php it will redirect to client.php file with this parameters. I dont know why you use file_get_contents it does not require i guess.

Comment: oh, I see, you want to redirect with the get params. that's also easy. answer updated.

Comment: thank you its redirecting but in url its passing information with null parameters...its not taking the variable value

Answer (score 1):

In your `login()` you are returning `$return`, that is wrong. You need to return `$result`, which is holding the result from `curl` request.

```
function login()
    {
        $wsdl = 'http://www.schwackenet.de/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl';
        $options = array('trace' => true);

        $params = array(
          'user' =>               utf8_encode('deshmukh'),
          'password' =>           utf8_encode('deshmukh'),
          'corporate_group_id' => '101',
          'dealer_number' =>      'INT31303',
          'dms_id' =>             'A13T2D19',
          'dms_image_url' =>      '', 
          'dms_keepalive_url' =>  '', 
          'dms_followup_url' =>   ''  
        );

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);  
        $result = $client->Login($params);      
        return $result;
    }

if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{       
    $vehicle=login();
    var_dump($vehicle);

  }
```

Comment: sorry i dont know how to use CURL request as i am new to web services

Comment: can u pass me the result of var_dump($vehicle)